# jsf with popups, problems with same viewid

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, view

I've a tomcat application with jsf 1.1

Case:
My application has a jsp (let name it /create.jsp) that contains a form to create a Business Object (imagine type person). One of the attributes of this Business Object is a relation to itself (the BO person, has an attribute father, that is also of type person). For this porpose, in the jsp, I have a selectable, and a button. The button enables to create new Business Object (in this case, a person). Therefore, the jsp show in the popup is the same that the one shown in the main window

Problem:
I'm facing wrong behaviours in the main window.

Cause:
I've studied the case, and the reason of the problem is the ids of the views stored in the server. When the users requires a new page, the server creates a view (ViewRoot) and stores it at the session. The jsp path is used as the id of the View. When the user submits a form, it will rehuse the same view stored in the session.
The problem in my case is that the popup ViewRoot, and the main window ViewRoot share the same id. So when the main window is shown, its viewRoot will be stored (let say id /create.jsp), but, when the popup is shown, its viewRoot will overwrite the main one in session. After closing the popup, the user will try to submit the main page, but in the server, there is no such a ViewRoot.

Possible Solution:
I've been thinking on changing the ViewRoot id creation, but I thing that this is not feasible (at least if I don't modify the jsf library).

---OLD TEXT---
I have a jsp with a form (let name it /create.jsp), that opens a popup window. This popup will also use /create.jsp .
Due to that JSF view-id, is fomed by the jsp path, both pages will share same id. So when the popup is displayed, the view stored in the session for the main page is overwritten by the new one. Because of this, the application is not working properly.

Is there any way to change the ids of the views? anyone has any solution?

Thanks

Comment: Note: the create.jsp is a generic page. I can't create a new one for the popup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final solution is the following:

1. Create a jsp name popup_create.jsp, that only contains an inlcude to the create.jsp
2. Duplicate create.jsp entry in facesconfig with popup_create.jsp
3. Create a ViewHandler (add it in config) with an extension of ViewHandlerImpl, where createView & restoreView methods are ovewritten, so that the viewId, in case that is create.jsp, and we are in a popup, it will modify the viewId to poup_create.jsp.

As I think this may be done in a more elegant way, it is the only way I've found.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look into using a subview . You can assign a name-space within this that will essentially create a new namespace within the page. In facelets that would be:

```
<f:view id="main">
  <ui:include "myOtherJsp.jsp" /> <!-- This containing a subview -->
</f:view>
```

Alternatively I think you may just need to separate the page into multiple views:

```
<f:view id="mainpage">
  <p>Page content</p>
</f:view>
<f:view id="popup">
  <p>My Popup</p>
</f:view>
```

I don't know the specifics of your application, but I can't see a situation where there's a reason to not have multiple views/forms. I'm guessing separation will fix your problem. You can use some elements of JSF outside the view ( so there's no reason to use a single view per page unless you're forced.

Caveat: I'm a JSF2 developer for the most part and I haven't done a JSF1.1 app in a long time.

Comment: `<ui:include>` is specific to Facelets and don't work in JSP. In JSP you normally use `<jsp:include>`.

Comment: I don't know how this can be used in my case. In the first solution I suppose that you mean creating a different jsp for the popup. This is not feasible in my case.
The second one, is not working nither. The popup and the main page contents are equal.

Comment: @Mateu I think there's a terminology problem here. You're specifically referencing a view. Are you using JSF or not? If you are, you can use the <jsp:include> mentioned by BalusC to bring in another JSP page as a subview.

Or, alternatively, you can separate the code so the views don't overlap. We likely need more information to be of any use.

Comment: I've modified the description of the problem. I think that now the problem is very clear. Thanks